# Which free program(s) for Windows can show how much time you spent today on each application?

Tags: windows, gratis, time-management, timer

I don't think there's any native solution for that on Windows and I hope there's a free solution out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to keep track of different tasks for different clients and sometimes forget to manually log the start and end times. I use [ActivityWatch](https://activitywatch.net/) to automatically keep track of software and web sites used and then distribute the activity analysis to my different time sheets. I will not consider online SaaS services and this one works well for me on Windows.

But there is tons of such software out there, for example, I just came accross this list of [20 Free Open-source Time Tracking Solutions](https://medevel.com/20-os-time-tracker-solutions-boost-productivity/). Looks interesting but I haven't tried the listed applications yet.